# Switching Git branches and disregarding changes

Tags: git, branch

I have a remote development server which I use to deploy changes to for client review, sometimes I might be working on 2 different branches and want to switch the remote server from one to another.

What is the correct method of doing so?

Assuming that my dev server has a clean checkout of 'origin/feature1' and I want to switch it to 'origin/feature2' with a single command... I had been using 'git checkout origin/feature2' but as far as I can tell this pulls all the files from 'feature2' into 'feature1'.

I want to switch branches and disregard anything that's changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout <branch> -f`

The -f option (or --force) will discard any working directory or index changes before switching to the branch.

Comment: Thanks. This response earns extra marks for being authored by a namesake.